# Is it possible to plot a chat like the below screenshot using highcharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have to plot a chart like below. In the chart, the column width should fill the gridline area. Is this possible in highcharts? Please ignore the line chart.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `pointPlacement: 'between'` and zero `pointPadding` and `groupPadding`:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    pointPlacement: 'between',
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p2q73rxy/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.groupPadding

Comment: Perfect.! This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much @ppotaczek